# Batch script to move MP3 from "Artist/Album1/Song.mp3" to "Artist/Song.mp3" for multiple albums?

Tags: batch-file, mp3, directory, move

I have music folder structured in subfolders as:

- **Artist1**

  - **Album1**

    - Song.mp3
  - **Album2**

    - AnotherSong.mp3
- **Artist2**

  - **Album1**

    - SomeSong.mp3
      etc..

And I would like to move the files to get:

- **Artist1**

  - Song.mp3
  - AnotherSong.mp3
- **Artist2**

  - SomeSong.mp3

Is there a batch command or script to run on the folder containing the artist folders and achieve this result?

Comment: What about duplicates?

Comment: There are no duplicates, the files are named in a unique way.

Answer (score 0):

As it can be read on help page [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) the Stack Overflow community should not be asked for making the entire job for you.

> Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

However, I wrote the batch file for this task and tested it although "moving files" tasks like this one can be done also easily with file managers, even with Windows Explorer.

```
@echo off
cd /D "C:\Path To\Artist\Folders"
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF
for /F "delims=" %%A in ( 'dir /AD /B /ON' ) do (
   echo.
   echo Moving files in %%A
   echo.
   for /F "delims=" %%B in ( 'dir "%%A" /AD /B /ON' ) do (
      move /Y "%%~fA\%%B\*" "%%~fA\"
      rmdir "%%~fA\%%B"
   )
)
```

The second line must be modified before the batch file can be used.

Enter in a command prompt window `help dir` or `dir /?` for a short description of the used options `/AD /B /ON`.